# UIWebview is not loading youtube videoes in iFrame

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

In my app I am using UIWebview to **Load Html string** which is having **Text,Image Url and Videos in iFrame**.This was working fine till now but recently I came to know that text and image url are loading fine and the video is not loading.I am just getting the blank space which I have allocated for the video but no sign of video.

The video iFrame which I am getting is this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Please suggest if something has changed in API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&fs=0' width='300' height='175' frameborder='0' >
    </iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tx77b/

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Even though it's correct not including some explanation makes the answer far less useful. The root problem seems to be that without a baseUrl set on the UIWebView, it won't infer http or https in the src attribute the way that a browser would.  The best solution I've seen is to set the baseURL, but that will break relative paths to resources (if you're downloading the HTML for instance). In that case, perhaps a string replace on src='// to add the http protocol explicitly?

Comment: 10+ @codercat : Its working man. And this is the only answer, because some URL schema is changed that's why it was happening. Thank a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

See this difference:

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A"

src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A"
```

If you want to use first one you have to add "http:" into your URL to make it valid link. You can do it very easy by adding some base URL when loading HTML string into UIWebView

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:"];
[self.contentWebView loadHTMLString:myHTMLCode
                            baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

//www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A uses scheme depends on server (http or https...etc).
In local HTML it will point to file://www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A.
I make a fake http host for loading:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:yourHTMLCode baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost"]];
```

This works for me.